How to make my SharePoint home page accessible to the public and profile page secured with login?
Accessing my SharePoint site currently needs login but I want the home page to be accessible to the entire public without any issue while the profile page would be accessible only by logging in.
How can I do this, please?

It's not possible anymore (since 2018) to open SharePoint Online site to anonymous users.
As an alternative, you can:

Use Power Pages which allows anonymous user;
Use SharePoint Online with external users (users are not part of your organization, but managed as guests and authenticated in your Entra ID).

Source: SharePoint Online Public Websites to be discontinued

With Power Pages, you pay a charge to Microsoft for each visitor and transaction. It's for B2B scenarios, not public facing web sites like a company profile.
